# Is it possible to 'protect' a property and exclude it from select statements

Tags: typeorm

I'd like to protect certain properties on the data-layer level. For example I'd like to protect the password hash I store in the database for a user, so that it doesn't show up in arbitrary `select`-statements.

This way only when it's explicitly requested in a `select property, property2` statement.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I think a more accurate answer would be to set `select: false` on column options:

```js
@Column({ select: false })
password: string;
```

And explicitly select the column like this:

```js
const user = await getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .addSelect('password')
    .getOne()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Here is a link to the docs: [hidden-columns](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns).
Nonetheless the accepted answer is a valid solution.

Answer (score 13):

TypeORM goes well with [routing-controllers](https://github.com/pleerock/routing-controllers) so you should use it, behind the scenes it uses [class-transformer](https://github.com/pleerock/class-transformer) to serialize and deserialize your data. So you can use the `@Exclude` decorator from that library to prevent certain properties being sent down to the clients.

It also uses the [class-validator](https://github.com/pleerock/class-validator) library to validate the data when specifying it as the type in the controller functions. These are powerful toys. Here is a small example of how you can leverage both:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Index, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { Exclude, Expose } from "class-transformer";
import { IsNotEmpty, IsEmail, MinLength, MaxLength, Min, Max, IsNumber, IsString } from "class-validator";

@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsEmail()
  @Index({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Exclude()
  @Column()
  passwordHash: string;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'integer', default: Gender.NotSpecified })
  @IsNumber()
  @Min(1)
  @Max(3)
  gender: Gender;


  @Expose()
  get admin() {
    return this.role == Role.Admin;
  }

  @Expose()
  get stylist() {
    return this.role == Role.Stylist;
  }
}
```

If you use an another server-side library you can still take advantage of *class-transformer* and *class-validator*. You just need to call the validate function manually in your routes, for example for restify you can write:

```
import {validate } from "class-validator";
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";
// ... more code

server.post('/hello', function create(req, res, next) {
   let bodyJSON = parseBodyTheWayYouWant(req.body);
   let post = plainToClass(bodyJSON);
   validate(post)
   return next();
});
```

Comment: This looks promising. But this is a non-documented feature right now, correct? At least not documented in TypeORM

Comment: I totally miss read your question. I have updated my answer to clarify this is the part or routing-conrollers which you really should use btw. Awesome product, and two goes well. (Take a look at typedi as well.)

Comment: Too bad I'm using restifyjs and not Koa or Expressjs

Comment: updated my answer with how to use it with different enviroments

Comment: goolged. found this. went to upvote. Apparently I already upvoted years ago, lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use delete

Exemple Find All users

```
async findUsers(){
   const users:User[] = await userRepository.find();

    return users.map(user => { 
        delete user.password;
        delete user.salt;
        return user;
    }) ;
}
```

Exemple Find User By Id

```
async findUserById(id){
   const user:User = await userRepository.findOne(id);
   delete user.password;
   return user;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/535
The simplest solution is to exclude field(s) during query.

Answer (score 0):

x.service.ts:

```
const data = await this.a.create(A);
await this.a.save(data);
return await this.a.findOneBy({ xx });
```

x.entity.ts

```
@Column({select:false}) // Key points for database queries [await this.a.findOneBy({ xx })]
xxx: string
```