# How to exclude entity field from returned by controller JSON. NestJS + Typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I want to exclude password field from returned JSON. 
I am using NestJS and Typeorm.

The solution provided on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726739/is-it-possible-to-protect-a-property-and-exclude-it-from-select-statements#44444496) doesn't work for me or in NestJS. I can post my code if needed.
Any other ideas or solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I'd suggest creating an interceptor that takes advantage of the [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library:

```
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    call$: Observable<any>,
  ): Observable<any> {
    return call$.pipe(map(data => classToPlain(data)));
  }
}
```

Then, simply exclude properties using `@Exclude()` decorator, for example:

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class User {
    id: number;
    email: string;

    @Exclude()
    password: string;
}
```

Comment: That's ti @kamil-myśliwiec :-D Best answer for the creator.

Comment: Thank you, @kamil-myśliwiec . I will try this asap.

Comment: Also, you can exclude fields during database query (in ORM, or SQL query). Example for TypeORM - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/535 .

Comment: I don't understand how to implement TransformInterceptor class in nest :( ?

Comment: The built in `ClassSerializerInterceptor` can be used here if im not mistaken

Comment: Is there anyway to do this with a prisma? Prisma doesn't seem to use the entity flow at all :(

Comment: @Kamil Myśliwiec and where to inject  TransformInterceptor class?

Answer (score 50):

You can overwrite the toJSON method of the model like this.

```js
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseAbstractEntity implements IUser {
  static passwordMinLength: number = 7;

  @ApiModelProperty({ example: faker.internet.email() })
  @IsEmail()
  @Column({ unique: true })
  email: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @MinLength(User.passwordMinLength)
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @Column({ select: false })
  password: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsString()
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @Column({ select: false })
  passwordSalt: string;

  toJSON() {
    return classToPlain(this);
  }

  validatePassword(password: string) {
    if (!this.password || !this.passwordSalt) {
      return false;
    }
    return comparedToHashed(password, this.password, this.passwordSalt);
  }
}
```

By using the class-transformer method of plainToClass along with the **@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })**, the password will be excluded from the JSON response, but will be available in the model instance. I like this solution because it keeps all the model configuration in the entity.

Comment: is there any document aboud toJSON() ?

Comment: toJSON method is a method that can be overriden in any javascript class. It defines how a class is converted to a regular object. When calling JSON.stringify, the toJSON method of the class is called. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

See the description section.

Comment: Only adding @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true }) was what I was looking for

Comment: `classToPlain` is now deprecated. Use `instanceToPlain` instead.

Answer (score 43):

Lots of good answers in this thread. To build on apun's answer above, I think the following approach is the least likely to accidentally leak a password field:

```
@Column({ select: false })
password: string
```

If the entity doesn't select that field by default, and it can only be explicitly queried (e.g. via `addSelect()` if using the query builder), I think it is a lot less likely that there's a slip somewhere, and there's less reliance on the "magic" of a framework (which is ultimately the `class-transformer` library) to ensure security. Realistically in many projects the only place you'd explicitly select it is where you check credentials.

This approach can also help keep the password hash from accidentally leaking into log entries, etc, which is a consideration that hasn't been mentioned yet. It feels much safer to toss around the user object knowing that it doesn't include sensitive information, especially if it could end up serialized in a log entry somewhere.

All said, the documented approach for NestJS is to use the `@Exclude()` decorator and the accepted answer is from the project's founder.

I definitely make frequent use of the `Exclude()` decorator, but not necessarily for password or salt fields.

Answer (score 40):

As an addition to [Kamil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372391/4694994):

Instead of creating your own interceptor, you can now use the built-in `ClassSerializerInterceptor`, see the [serialization docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization).

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```

You can use it on a controller class or its individual methods. Each entity returned by such a method will be transformed with class-transformer and hence take the `@Exclude` annotations into account:

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class User {
    /** other properties */    

    @Exclude()
    password: string;
}
```

---

You can customize its behavior by defining `@SerializeOptions()` on your controller or its methods:

```
@SerializeOptions({
  excludePrefixes: ['_'],
  groups: ['admin']
})
```

to, for example, expose certain fields only to certain users:

```
@Expose({ groups: ["admin"] })
adminInfo: string;
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know if the built-in class supports defining groups, i.e `@Expose({ groups: ["user", "admin"] })`? I've been struggling to figure out how you'd indicate which group should be used from within the controller. From the `class-transformer` docs I can see it supports `classToPlain(user, { groups: ["user"] })`, but I'm a little confused where nest is calling it, and if I can pass through those options.

Comment: just a newbie question: where do you define the "groups", i.e how class-transformer would know which group the user is in? shall we define Group model first and make user has multiple groups kinda relation? i.e the user would have user.groups = ['editor', user']? Then how do we pass the user of the current request to the intercepter so it would show/hide fields accordingly?

Comment: @AhmetCetin The `SerializeOptions` only work if the `groups` are static per endpoint. If you want to dynamically determine the `groups` based on the request, you have to implement a custom interceptor for that.

Comment: See this answer, where the groups are dynamically determined for validation, you need to do something similar, but for serialization (in your case interceptor instead of pipe): https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057206/4694994

Comment: @KimKern, `@Expose` did not work as expected on method level on `POST` request. I am using nestjs `6.5.3`

Comment: @ddsultan Please open a new question about this; it's not possible to debug your issue in the comments without more details: a minimal example so that the problem can be reproduced and your expected behavior or output. Thanks :-)

Comment: Check [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68877535/15301406) as below for how to use class-transformer groups in a dynamic way in Nestjs.

Answer (score 5):

```
@Column({ select: false })
password: string
```

Can read about hidden columns [here](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns)

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Sure. I thought it was self explanatory.

Answer (score 2):

what simply worked for me was just

annotating the field with @Exclude and overiding toJSON model method like so

`toJSON() { return classToPlain(this); }`

Comment: Awesome. My problem solved with it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

You can exclude a properties using decorators and also, you can exlude properties using groups.

Comment: Silva, Could you please point out a reference to "exlude properties using groups."? I was not able find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is already an old topic, but I still would like to share my solution, maybe it will help somebody. I use Express, but my example is probably suitable for this case as well.

So in your entity class you just define an additional static `removePassword()` method, which receives an instance of entity itself, and you send an object created by this method instead of original entity object you got from DB:

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'users' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string | undefined;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100, unique: true })
  email: string | undefined;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  password: string | undefined;

  static removePassword(userObj: User) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(userObj).filter(([key, val]) => key !== 'password')
    );
  }
}
```

This is basically like calling a `filter()` method on an array, but slightly more complicated: you create a new object (the one you'll send eventually) from entries array, produced by filtering out a password entry from original entries array (with this exact `filter()` method).

In your route handlers though you'll just always do something like this:

```js
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { User } from '../../entity/User';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';

const router = Router();

router.post(
  '/api/users/signin',
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    getRepository(User)
      .findOne({ email })
      .then(user =>
        user ? res.send(User.removePassword(user)) : res.send('No such user:(')
      )
      .catch(err => next(new Error(err.message)));
  }
);

export { router as signinRouter };
```

You may also use regular method:

```js
withoutPassword() {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(this).filter(([key, val]) => key !== 'password')
  );
}
```

and in your route handler:

```js
res.send(user.withoutPassword());
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any back-pain and headaches,
I would suggest using the `plainToClass` to have a full mongoose/class-transform compatibility and avoid having to make custom overrides to overcome this isse.

Example, add this in your service :

```
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserWithoutPassword | null> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne({ email });

    if (user && await compare(password, user.password))
    {
        return plainToClass(UserWithoutPassword, user.toObject());
    }

    return null;
}
```

Source : [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546812/typescript-mongoose-ignore-certain-field-in-query-result-the-type-safe-way)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/15301406) for Nestjs.

How to use class-transformer groups in a dynamic way since the groups are fixed in the function decorator `@SerializeOptions`. Put the dynamic groups in `classToClass` or `plainToClass`.

```
@Post()
@SerializeOptions({
  groups: ['admin','user'],
})
async create(
  @Body() createProjectDto: CreateProjectDto,
) {
  const data = await this.projectsService.create(createProjectDto);
  return classToClass(data, { groups: ['admin','DYNAMIC_GROUP'] });
  //Or you can return
  //return plainToClass(Project, plainObject, {groups: ['admin','DYNAMIC_GROUP']});
}
```

The `classToClass` and `plainToClass` inside the function body do the actual filtering while `@SerializeOptions` to make sure the filtered data will be returned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export default class TransformInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    next: CallHandler,
  ): Observable<AnyObject> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map((args) => instanceToPlain(args)));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please accompany your answer with an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Whoever comes across this question in the future might also consider using the approach I suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75436936/4397899