# NestJS - Validating body conditionally, based on one property

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

I'm trying to find a nice way to validate a body using DTO (using the brilliant `class-validator` and `class-transformer` libraries). It works really well, even for nested structures but in my case I'd like to have the body property based on some conditions.

Example that will probably help to understand:

Let's imagine my body should always have `selectedCategory`.
Based on that field, the content could either be from category 1, which contains `prop1` OR from category 2, which contains `prop2`.

I do not want to allow a null for both of them, I really want to have to either have `prop1` defined or `prop2` based on the `selectedCategory`.

I think that I could use a pipe, but then how can I specify the correct DTO to use?

I've built a "base" class with all the common properties and few other classes that inherit from it.

I could instantiate the pipe manually based on the property `selectedCategory`, that'd be ideal but I have no clue what to pass as a second argument of the pipe (metadata).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this if your variable is defined in the request (as a param) rather than a variable in the body?

Comment: I'm afraid not, I haven't been working with NestJS for a while now. If you find out it might be interesting to post an answer here though :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have you tried using [groups](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-groups)?
Instead of having multiple DTOs, you just create one DTO. Every property is assigned to one or multiple groups:

```
@Min(12, {groups: ['registration', 'update']})
age: number;
@Length(2, 20, {groups: ['registration']})
name: string;
```

You can then conditionally pass the groups to class transformer / validator:

```
@Injectable()
export class ConditionalValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  async transform(entity: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    // Dynamically determine the groups
    const groups = [];
    if (entity.selectedCategory === 1) {
      groups.push('registration');
    }

    // Transform to class with groups
    const entityClass = plainToClass(EntityDto, entity, { groups })

    // Validate with groups
    const errors = await validate(entityClass, { groups });
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw this.createError(errors);
    }
    return entityClass;
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you have `this.createError` defined?

Comment: @EddieMongeJr Wherever you want to define your custom error handling, e.g., directly in the pipe. Also, have a look at the validation errors: https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validation-errors

Comment: Dou you have an example on how tonuse that pipe in a controller?

Comment: @Blackfaded Have a look at the binding pipes docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#binding-pipes

Comment: Did anyone tried a FluentValidation style? like: https://fluentvalidation-ts.alexpotter.dev/docs/overview.html

Comment: What about types for conditional undefined prop? Taking your example, I'm expecting on `update` that the `dto.name` in controller is `undefined`

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried the [ValidateIf](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#conditional-validation) statement?

You can have multiple validations for `props1` or `props2` and apply them if `selectedCategory` is "category 1" or "category 2" accordingly.