# NestJS strategy for excluding fields for different user roles?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

Let's say I have a base entity, `ShopsEntity`, that has a bunch of fields along with a secret property:

```js
@ObjectType()
class ShopsEntity {

   @Field()
   name: string;

   @Field()
   rating: string;

   @Field()
   secret: string;
}
```

I don't want the secret property to be serialised unless a user has a certain role defined through [Nest Access Control](https://github.com/nestjsx/nest-access-control) (That module only allows for RoleGuards to be placed on the resolvers themselves, meaning I would need different routes per role).

So, following a request to the same endpoint with differing levels of authentication, an Admin would get:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "rating": "rating",
  "secret": "secret"
}
```

and a regular querying user would get:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "rating": "rating"
}
```

Is there a declarative way in which I can do property-level security here, or is the best solution having separate DTO's for each level of security?

Comment: I use the `groups` feature of class-transformer, which I use for the serialization (or resp. class-validator for validation). I'm not sure if it interoperates with your access controll library. Have a look at https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#using-groups-to-control-excluded-properties and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057206/4694994

Comment: yep, looks like `groups` is the way to go! Integrates very nicely with access-control as I can reimport the roles used there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With class-transformer, you can use the [`groups` property](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#using-groups-to-control-excluded-properties) to expose properties only for certain groups/roles:

```
import {Exclude, Expose} from "class-transformer";

@Exclude()
export class User {

    @Expose({ groups: ["admin"] })
    secret: string;
}
```

On how to use the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` with groups, see the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/4694994).

Comment: How would you declare in the controller which groups it should serialize?

Comment: @Joel If the groups are static for the endpoint, you can use the following approach, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/4694994