# How can I change the property name of a serialized entity with toJSON?

Tags: node.js, typescript, serialization, nestjs, class-transformer

I want to serialize a property with a different name than it has in the entity.

```
@Entity()
export class MyEntity {
  // This should be serialized with name_column in JSON
  @Column()
  name: string
}
```

When I call `classToPlain` I want the property `name` to be serialized to `name_column`:

```
classToPlain(myEntity)
// returns: {name: 'my name'}
// should be: {name_column: 'my name'}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text, explain the error, see [mcve] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you are using `json-typescript-mapper` instead of [`class-transformer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/4694994), which is natively supported by nest.js?

---

With `class-transformer`, you can change the name of a column with `@Expose`:

```
@Expose({ name: "name_column" })
name: string;
```

For the serialization, you can just annotate your controller class or individual methods with `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)`. With the annotation, it will automatically serialize all entities, that you return from a controller method. You can read more about this in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/4694994).

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer only works if you're directly calling `classToPlain` on the model entity.

---

If you have a separate DTO class, you'll be calling `plainToClass` and then `classToPlain`, which will cause it to be either blank or keep the original name.

Another approach you could take to change the name is exposing a getter function instead:

```
@Expose({ toClassOnly: true })
name: string;

@Expose({ toPlainOnly: true })
get column_name(): string {
   return this.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Expose()` with `instanceToPlain` to override the property name at runtime.
`classToPlain` has been deprecated, name is changed to `instanceToPlain` now.

`@Expose`:

```
@Expose({ name: "name_column" })
name: string;
```

and where you initialize the class use below code to set Exposed names.

```
instanceToPlain(new MyEntity({
  name: 'Harry'
}));
```

This will change name to `name_column` at runtime.