# Nest js - Change capital letter for dashed in ToJSON method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I have the method:

```
@Entity()
export class Picklist extends BaseD2CEntity {
  @ApiHideProperty()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'picklist_name' })
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty({ type: String, description: 'picklist_name' })
  picklistName: string;

  toJSON() {
    return classToPlain(this);
  }

}
```

At the moment to serialize the object, with:

`myPicklist.picklist.toJSON();` I get:

`{ id: 7, picklistName: "status", }`

What is correct.
But, I need to replace the capital letter of `picklistName` and replace it for `_` like, `picklist_name`, as in the decorator `@Column`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Why dont you rename the attribute `picklistName` to `picklist_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Expose properties with different name

You can expose properties with a different name in the serialization with class-transformer's `@Expose` decorator, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267732/4694994):

```
@Expose({ name: 'picklist_name' })
picklistName: string;
```

#### Built-in ClassSerializerInterceptor

Instead of defining the `toJSON` method yourself, you can use the built-in `ClassSerializerInterceptor` to automatically serialize your entities when returning them from a controller method, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/4694994).

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
```