# How to rename JSON fields in nest.js

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, fastify

I would like to know what's the correct way to rename a field for only the deserializer in `nest.js`. For the given object below:

```js
export class User {

  contact_email?: string;

}
```

`contact_email` is a field in our database but it conflicts with the current apps were are sending `contactEmail`.

I tried the given solutions below:

```js
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

export class User {

  @Expose({ name: "contactEmail" })
  contact_email?: string;

}
```

This one above renames the field at all and when using the object, it's transformed to `contactEmail` at all, not only when transforming from JSON (string) to Class. Then I tried the solution below:

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class User {

  @Transform(key => "contactEmail", { toClassOnly: true })
  contact_email?: string;

}
```

This case seems to not be working too.

The info coming from the application:

```json
{
  "contactEmail": "email@gmail.com"
}
```

I would like to do something similar to rust's serde [#rename](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#rename). Where I can rename a field for the serialization/deserialization but keep the original name for the application.

We are using nest.js + fastify.js + sequelize.js.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem Pedro. Docs suggest `@Expose({name:''})` should be working: https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#exposing-properties-with-different-names - but alas. I also tried the approach - https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/527 without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so after some digging, I have a workaround, but as you will see it's an ugly duckling / hack :

```
  @Expose()
  @Transform(
    ({value, obj, type}) => {
      console.log(value, obj, type);
      if (obj['contact_email']) {
        return obj['contact_email'];
      } else {
        return value;
      }
    }
  )
  contactEmail?: string;
```

Does that work for you?

Using a ternary statement to trim it down a bit:

```
  @Expose()
  @Transform(
    ({value, obj}) =>
      typeof value === 'undefined' ? obj['contact_email'] : value
  )
  contactEmail?: string;
```

I should probably seek clarification on `class-transform` project, as I suspect this isn't intended.

I noticed after putting logs inside the `@Transform` decorator that on the first pass through `value` was `undefined`, but then on the 2nd pass it had a value.

I know it's getting called twice, I think once on calling `plainToClass`, then again during serialisation.

Hopefully this workaround is helpful or pushes the issue along for you.

Comment: how to change the key? e.g. ```contactEmail2023```

Comment: I think `@Transform` is only for value, for key you might want something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267732/3080207 (it's been a while since I've played w/ this stuff)