# Serialization: How to exclude Entity columns in json response but not internal queries in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

**Edit**:
*I have looked at this question/answer [How to exclude entity field from controller json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360101/how-to-exclude-entity-field-from-returned-by-controller-json-nestjs-typeorm)

But, as per below - this is excluding that field from all queries (to the porint where when trying to process user validation, the password field is excluded using the findOne repository query on a route/controller method that does not have ClassSerializerInterceptor*

I have an entity within nest.js / typeorm; I am trying to exclude the password field from the returned json, but not exclude the password field from any repository queries within my service. For example:

`user.entity.ts`:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, CreateDateColumn, 
UpdateDateColumn, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';
import { Account } from '../accounts/account.entity';

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({
    unique: true,
  })
  email: string;

 @Column()
 password: string;
}
```

`auth.controller.ts`:

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, Request, Req, Get, UseInterceptors, ClassSerializerInterceptor, UseGuards } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { IUserRequest } from '../../interfaces/user-request.interface';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @Post('/login')
  async login(@Request() req: Request) {
    const user = await this.authService.checkCredentials(req.body);
    return this.authService.logUserIn(user.id);
  }

  @Get('/profile')
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  async profile(@Request() req: IUserRequest) {
    const profile = await this.authService.getLoggedInProfile(req.user.id);
    return { profile };
  }
}
```

If I add `Exclude()` to password like so

```
@Exclude()
@Column()
password: string;
```

the password is included in the response

If I remove the `Column()` from password,

```
@Exclude()
password: string;
```

Password is excluded from response **and** all internal queries such as:

```
const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { id }, relations: ['account']});
```

Is this possible in nest.js using the `ClassSerializerInterceptor`?

If so, would appreciate a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can skip properties [depending on the operation](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/README.md#skipping-depend-of-operation). In your case, you would use:

```
@Column()
@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
password: string;
```

This means, that password is only skipped when a class is transformed to json (when you send a response) and not when json is transformed to a class (when you get a request).

Then add the `@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)` to your controller or a controller method. This will automatically transform an entity class to json, when you return it.

---

For the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` to work, make sure that your entity was transformed to a class first. This can be automatically done by using the `ValidationPipe` with the `{ transform: true}` option or by returning an entity from a repository (database). Also, you have to return the entity itself:

```
@Post()
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
addUser(@Body(new ValidationPipe({transform: true})) user: User) {
  // Logs user with password
  console.log(user);
  // Returns user as JSON without password
  return user;
  }
```

Otherwise, you have to transform it manually:

```
async profile(@Request() req: IUserRequest) {
  // Profile comes from the database so it will be an entity class instance already
  const profile = await this.authService.getLoggedInProfile(req.user.id);
  // Since we are not returning the entity directly, we have to transform it manually
  return { profile: plainToClass(profile) };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, for some reason, this still did not work with the @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor).


However, adding the class-transform @TransformClassToPlain()  did the trick

Comment: Ahh, I only just saw that you are not returning the entity directly. The `ClassSerializerInterceptor` will only work, if the entity itself is returned, so `return profile` instead of `return {profile}`. If you are not returning it directly, you have to transform it manually with `plainToClass()`.

Comment: not working for me. i also have made this interceptor global. yet couldn't exclude password field on post response.

Answer (score 4):

Would advice also looking at [TypeOrm hidden-columns](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/hidden-columns) 
Here you have `@Column({select: false})` on your password column , all requests using a standard find or query will exclude the password column.

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
id: number;

@Column()
name: string;

@Column({select: false})
password: string;
}
```

Then during validations/cases where you need the password you do

```
const users = await connection.getRepository(User)
.createQueryBuilder()
.select("user.id", "id")
.addSelect("user.password")
.getMany();
```