# serializering response in Nest.js

Tags: serialization, nestjs

I have a NEST.JS project, and when client Gets user, i want to filter field of "password" of user. But It Did not Exclude that and returns all field(also `pssword` field)!

it is user's directory structure:

[image]

.
I Excluded the `password` field in `user.serializer.ts` like that:

```
    export class UserSerializer implements IUser {
firstname : string;
lastname : string;
username : string;
email : string;
isEmailVerified : boolean;
isPhoneVerified : boolean;
phoneNumber : string;
nationalCode : string;
shebaCode : string;
roles : string[];

@Exclude()
password : string;
```

}

and it is `user.service.ts` :

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private userRepository: UserRepository){}
async geOneCustomer(userId: string): Promise<UserSerializer>{
    let result = await this.userRepository.findOne({
                where:{
                id: userId
                }
        });
    if(!result) throw new NotFoundResponse({result:[], message:'Ooops! Not found Suc A User!', statusCode:404, metaData:[]});
    return result
```

}

and it is `user.controller.ts` :

```
@Controller('/')
  export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  @Get('/admin/user/customer/:userId')
  async geOneCustomer(@Param('userId') userId: string ) : Promise<UserSerializer>{
        return await this.userService.geOneCustomer(userId);
  }
```

but, when i try the route of `'/admin/user/customer/:userId'` i get also field of `password` !
it do not Excludes `password` field!

i don't want to Exclude the password field in `user.entity.ts` .
because `user.entity.ts` is related to saving data in DB and precenting result to client, must have separate logic and implementation.

i have seen NEST.JS serializing DOC, an so much articles about that, but i could not handle that!
CAN ANY ONE Help?

Answer (score 0):

You need your `UserService#geOneCustomer` to return an instance of a `UserSerializer` class so that the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` sees the right class type and can properly run `classToPlain` on it and pick up the correct metadata

ETA very abstract idea from existing code

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private userRepository: UserRepository){}
async geOneCustomer(userId: string): Promise<UserSerializer>{
    let result = await this.userRepository.findOne({
                where:{
                id: userId
                }
        });
    if(!result) throw new NotFoundResponse({result:[], message:'Ooops! Not found Suc A User!', statusCode:404, metaData:[]});
    const returnResult = new UserSerializer(result);
    return returnResult;
}
```

Of course, passing in the object directly is probably not going to be the best option, but it'll be the quickest.

Comment: thanks, but i could not implement this way. can give a boiler plate or sample code like that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will help in your case https://stackoverflow.com/a/54335852/19515543, like it mentioned in the solution. You can use `plainToClass(result)`

or

In entity make password field like below.

```
@Column({select: false})
password: string;
```

with above implementation you can simply execute this line

```
const result = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where:{ id: userId }});
console.log(result);
```

Hope this helps.