# class serialization not working in nestjs

Tags: serialization, nestjs, class-transformer, typegoose

I've a simple user model and i want to exclude password from it. Using the [official docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) and [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54277187/9014038) i've tried to make it work but this doesn't seem to work as i get a response something like this.

```json
[
  {
    "$__": {
      "strictMode": true,
      "selected": {},
      "getters": {},
      "_id": {
        "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
        "id": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            94,
            19,
            73,
            179,
            3,
            138,
            216,
            246,
            182,
            234,
            62,
            37
          ]
        }
      },
      "wasPopulated": false,
      "activePaths": {
        "paths": {
          "password": "init",
          "email": "init",
          "name": "init",
          "_id": "init",
          "__v": "init"
        },
        "states": {
          "ignore": {},
          "default": {},
          "init": {
            "_id": true,
            "name": true,
            "email": true,
            "password": true,
            "__v": true
          },
          "modify": {},
          "require": {}
        },
        "stateNames": [
          "require",
          "modify",
          "init",
          "default",
          "ignore"
        ]
      },
      "pathsToScopes": {},
      "cachedRequired": {},
      "session": null,
      "$setCalled": [],
      "emitter": {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0,
        "_maxListeners": 0
      },
      "$options": {
        "skipId": true,
        "isNew": false,
        "willInit": true
      }
    },
    "isNew": false,
    "_doc": {
      "_id": {
        "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
        "id": {
          "type": "Buffer",
          "data": [
            94,
            19,
            73,
            179,
            3,
            138,
            216,
            246,
            182,
            234,
            62,
            37
          ]
        }
      },
      "name": "Kamran",
      "email": "kamran@example.com",
      "password": "Pass1234",
      "__v": 0
    },
    "$locals": {},
    "$init": true
  }
]
```

Here's my model. I'm using `Typegoose` but the same is the case with `Mongoose` as well.

```js
export class User extends Typegoose {
  @Transform((value) => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })
  _id: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public email!: string;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @prop({ required: true })
  public password!: string;
}
```

My user service

```js
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User) private readonly user: ReturnModelType<typeof User>) {}

  async getUsers() {
    return this.user.find().exec();
  }
}
```

and user controller

```js
@Controller('users')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class UserController {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}

  @Get()
  async index() : Promise<User[] | []> {
    return this.userService.getUsers();
  }
}
```

I tried to use my custom interceptor as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50372391/9014038) but that didn't work so i changed it to below code as given [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/nestjs/nest/930/532992582)

```js
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => classToPlain(this.transform(data))));
  }

  transform(data) {
    const transformObject = (obj) => {
      const result = obj.toObject();
      const classProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(new User());
      Object.setPrototypeOf(result, classProto);
      return result;
    }

    return Array.isArray(data) ? data.map(obj => transformObject(obj)) : transformObject(data);
  }
}
```

Now it's working but the code is not generic. Any way to make it generic?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @JPYamamoto i just posted my solution. Give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i've identified the problem but not sure why this happens yet. So here's the problem if i return the instance of the class then the serialization works but if i just return plain db response then the above mentioned issue occurs. So what i did is i updated the prototype of the response objects in the `transform` method of `toObject` to my user class. Here's the code.

> User Model

```js
@modelOptions({
  schemaOptions: {
    toObject: {
      transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
        Object.setPrototypeOf(ret, Object.getPrototypeOf(new User()));
      }
    },
  },
})
export class User {
  @Transform((value) => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })
  public _id: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public name!: string;

  @prop({ required: true })
  public email!: string;

  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  @prop({ required: true })
  public password!: string;
}
```

> TransformInterceptor

```js
@Injectable()
export class TransformInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(map(data => classToPlain(this.transform(data))));
  }

  transform(data) {
    return Array.isArray(data) ? data.map(obj => obj.toObject()) : data.toObject();
  }
}
```

And now if you just decorate your controller or method with `@UseInterceptors(TransformInterceptor)` it will work perfectly. This is a `typegoose` solution but it will work the same way with `mongoose` as well.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to do this with Typegoose?

Comment: @JPYamamoto i've updated my answer with `typegoose` using a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

@kamran-arshad answer helped me find an appropriate way to accomplish the expected result with typegoose. You can use the decorator `@modelOptions()` and pass it an object with a function to generate the JSON.

```js
@modelOptions({
  toJSON: {
    transform: function(doc, ret, options) {
      delete ret.password;
      return ret;
    }
  }
})
export class User extends Typegoose {
@prop({required: true})
name!: string;

@prop({required: true})
password!: string;
}
```

It is not perfect, as decorators from the `class-transform` do not work as expected, but it gets the job done. Also, you should avoid using the `ClassSerializerInterceptor` because it will give the same result that OP mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any back-pain and headaches with Mongoose,
I would suggest using the `plainToClass` to have a full mongoose/class-transform compatibility and avoid having to make custom overrides to overcome this isse.

Example, add this in your service :

```js
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserWithoutPassword | null> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne({ email });

    if (user && await compare(password, user.password))
    {
        return plainToClass(UserWithoutPassword, user.toObject());
    }

    return null;
}
```

This way you can use the `@Exclude()` and other decorators

Source : [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546812/typescript-mongoose-ignore-certain-field-in-query-result-the-type-safe-way)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, all the Decorators will work without needing the `ClassSerializerInterceptor`

```
PersonSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  return plainToClass(Person, this.toObject());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Exclude, Expose } from "class-transformer";

export class UserSerializer {

    @Expose()
    email: string;
    @Expose()
    fullName: string;
    @Exclude()
    password: string;

    @Expose()
    username: string;
}
```

```js
 @Post("new")
    async createNewAccount(@Body() body: CreateUserDTO) {
        return plainToClass(UserSerializer, await (await this.authService.createNewUser(body)).toJSON())
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me: `@Transform(({value}) => value.toHexString(), {toPlainOnly: true})`

Full code example:

```js
export class User {
    @ObjectIdColumn()
    @Transform(({value}) => value.toHexString(), {toPlainOnly: true})
    _id: ObjectID

    @Column({unique: true })
    username: string

    @Column({ unique: true })
    email: string

    @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
    @Column()
    password: string
}
```