# How to serialize a nest js response with class-transformer while getting data with Typegoose?

Tags: serialization, response, nestjs, class-transformer, typegoose

I have been trying to work through the NestJs example for the Serialization Section for Mongodb using Typegoose using the class-transformer library. The example given at https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization only shows how to use serialization in TypeORM. I followed the same process for Typegoose. Here is what I have tried so far.

```
// cat.domain.ts

import { prop } from '@typegoose/typegoose';

export class Cat {
  @prop()
  name: string;

  @prop()
  age: number;

  @prop()
  breed: string;
}


// cats.service.ts

@Injectable()
export class CatsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Cat) private readonly catModel: ReturnModelType<typeof Cat>,
  ) {}

  findAll(): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return from(this.catModel.find().exec());
  }

  findOne(id: string): Observable<Cat> {
    return from(this.catModel.findById(id).exec());
  }
  ...
}

// cat.response.ts

import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
import { Exclude, Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class CatResponse {
  @Transform(value => value.toString(), { toPlainOnly: true })
  _id?: ObjectId;

  name: string;

  age: number;

  @Exclude()
  breed: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<CatResponse>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

// cats.controller.ts

@Controller('cats')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll(): Observable<CatResponse[]> {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }

  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param() params: FindOneParamsDto): Observable<CatResponse> {
    return this.catsService.findOne(params.id);
  }
  ...
}
```

I tried running the API call on Get() with id but instead of the `breed` being excluded from the response I have been getting the following response.

```
{
    "$__": {
        "strictMode": true,
        "selected": {},
        "getters": {},
        "_id": {
            "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
            "id": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    94,
                    93,
                    76,
                    66,
                    116,
                    204,
                    248,
                    112,
                    147,
                    216,
                    167,
                    205
                ]
            }
        },
        "wasPopulated": false,
        "activePaths": {
            "paths": {
                "_id": "init",
                "name": "init",
                "age": "init",
                "breed": "init",
                "__v": "init"
            },
            "states": {
                "ignore": {},
                "default": {},
                "init": {
                    "_id": true,
                    "name": true,
                    "age": true,
                    "breed": true,
                    "__v": true
                },
                "modify": {},
                "require": {}
            },
            "stateNames": [
                "require",
                "modify",
                "init",
                "default",
                "ignore"
            ]
        },
        "pathsToScopes": {},
        "cachedRequired": {},
        "$setCalled": [],
        "emitter": {
            "_events": {},
            "_eventsCount": 0,
            "_maxListeners": 0
        },
        "$options": {
            "skipId": true,
            "isNew": false,
            "willInit": true
        }
    },
    "isNew": false,
    "_doc": {
        "_id": {
            "_bsontype": "ObjectID",
            "id": {
                "type": "Buffer",
                "data": [
                    94,
                    93,
                    76,
                    66,
                    116,
                    204,
                    248,
                    112,
                    147,
                    216,
                    167,
                    205
                ]
            }
        },
        "name": "Sylver",
        "age": 14,
        "breed": "Persian Cat",
        "__v": 0
    },
    "$locals": {},
    "$op": null,
    "$init": true
}
```

Can anyone help me with how to serialize response properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UPDATE:
class-transformer now works correctly with typegoose, [look here for the documentation on how to use it](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/integration-examples/using-with-class-transformer)

---

[this is an known issue](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/known-issues) ([#108](https://github.com/typegoose/typegoose/issues/108)), typegoose (& mongoose) are incompatible with class-transformer/class-validator
this is because typegoose needs to translate the class into an schema and mongoose will compile it to an model (which isnt the class anymore)

Comment: how would u suggest I exclude items from my response? I was thinking of doing something similar to that like create a Transform Interceptor along with a custom decorator and check for the decorator in the interceptor but that seems like a lot of work and I m not that experienced yet. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: when it is some value like "password" you can set "select: false" as an `@prop` option and it is by default not included in any query without explicitly selecting it again, otherwise transform it to an [POJO](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/pojo) (either by `.toJSON` or `.lean`) and filtering out anything that you dont want (blacklist / whitelist)

Comment: How to serialize a nest js response with class-transformer while getting data with MONGOOSE?

Comment: link in the answer says "404 Not found".

Comment: @RollerCosta, i have updated the links

Answer (score 3):

### For people trying to follow nestjs documentation & using mongoose but `ClassSerializerInterceptor` not working.

Posting a solution for using class-transformer withe mongoose below which can be helpful for others, it uses custom interceptor that you can see in the nest documentation. https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors

```
How the folder structure would be:  
  
src
└── cats
    ├── dto
    │   └── cats-response.dto.ts
    ├── interceptor
    │   └── cats.interceptor.ts
    ├── schemas
    │   └── cat.schema.ts
    ├── cats.controller.ts
    └── cats.service.ts
```

1. We will create a dto for cat response called `CatsResponseDto` in `cats-response.dto.ts` & in it exclude the `breed` property from response using Exclude() decorator. By using Dto for response we will create the instance of `CatsResponseDto`
2. We will create custom interceptor for cats response called `CatsInterceptor` in `cats.interceptor.ts`. You can generate it using nest cli, the command is `nest g interceptor cats`

**cats-response.dto.ts**
Create `CatsResponseDto` to be used in our custom interceptor.

```js
import { Expose, Exclude } from 'class-transformer'

export class CatsResponseDto {

  @Expose()
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  age: number;

  // Exclude decorator to exclude it from our response.
  @Exclude()
  breed: string;

}
```

**cats.interceptor.ts**
Create out custom `CatsInterceptor`
Note: plainToClass has been deprecated & now called plainToInstance, I only got to know when used it on my Ide and it prompted. The official documentation yet not updated. https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#plaintoclass

The changelog does mention about it.
https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/blob/develop/CHANGELOG.md#041-breaking-change---2021-11-20

```js
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from '@nestjs/common';
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer'
import { map, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { CatsResponseDto } from '../dto/cats-response.dto'

@Injectable()
export class CatsInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, handler: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    
    return handler.handle().pipe(
      map((data: any) => {
        
        // run something before the response is sent out.
        // Please note that plainToClass is deprecated & is now called plainToInstance
        
        return plainToInstance(CatsResponseDto, data, {
        
        // By using excludeExtraneousValues we are ensuring that only properties decorated with Expose() decorator are included in response.
          
        excludeExtraneousValues: true,

        })
      })
    );

  }
}
```

Our cat schema must have been defined like below (for reference) in `cat.schema.ts` or similar as per mongoose documentation.

**cat.schema.ts**

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type CatDocument = Cat & Document;

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Cat {

  // no Id defined here as its automatically added by mongoose unless we explicitly provide option to turn it OFF in schema options.  
    
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  age: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  breed: string;

}

export const CatSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Cat);
```

Now bind our custom interceptor `CatsInterceptor` in `cats.controller.ts`

**cats.controller.ts**

```js
import { Cat } from './schemas/cat.schema';
import { CatsInterceptor } from './interceptor/cats.interceptor';
import { CatsService } from './cats.service.ts'

@Controller('cats')
export class CatsController {
  constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}

  @Get()
  findAll(): Promise<Cat[]> {
    return this.catsService.findAll();
  }

  @UseInterceptors(CatsInterceptor)
  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param() params: FindOneParamsDto): Promise<Cat> {
    return this.catsService.findOne(params.id);
  }
  ...
}
```

**RESULT**: when calling /cats/{id} response would exclude breed.

related issue:
[class serialization not working in nestjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718344/class-serialization-not-working-in-nestjs)

Comment: what about _id ?

Comment: id is the id of the cat that you are trying to get.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround:

`cats.controller.ts`:

```js
    import { plainToInstance } from "class-transformer";

    @Controller('cats')
    @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
    export class CatsController {
      constructor(private readonly catsService: CatsService) {}
    
      @Get()
      findAll(): Observable<CatResponse[]> {
        const cats = this.catsService.findAll();
        // transforming the Model to CatResponse class...
        const catResponses = cats.map(cat => classToPlain(new CatResponse(cat.toJSON())))
        return catResponses;
      }
    
      @Get(':id')
      findOne(@Param() params: FindOneParamsDto): Observable<CatResponse> {
        const cat = this.catsService.findOne(params.id);
        const catResponse = plainToInstance(new CatResponse(cat.toJSON()));
        return 
      }
      ...
    }
```

Hope it could help.