# NestJS problem with ClassSerializerInterceptor in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm trying to work with [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) and [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/). I'm building an API based on Mongoose and GraphQL.
This is how I'm using Exclude decorator in one of my GraphQL objects:

```js
@ObjectType('user')
export class User extends Teacher {
  @Field()
  login: string;
    
  @Field()
  @Exclude()
  password: string;
}
```

And this is my method in UserResolver used with **ClassSerializerInterceptor**:

```js
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Mutation(returns => User, { name: 'editUserById', nullable: true })
async editById(
  @Args('id') id: string,  
  @Args({ name: "item", type: () => UserInputType }) item: UserInputType
) {
  const user = await this.usersService.editById(id, item);
  return user;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to get from this mutation user fields without a password (which is excluded in GraphQL object). But unfortunately, all fields are null. Error example from GraphQL playground:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field user.firstName.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "editUserById",
        "firstName"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "editUserById": null
  }
}
```

Teacher object:

```js
@ObjectType('teacher')
@InputType()
export class Teacher {
  @Field()
  _id: string;

  @Field()
  firstName: string;

  @Field()
  lastName: string;

  @Field(type => [String], { nullable: true })
  schoolsIds: string[];

  @Field(type => [School], { nullable: true })
  schools: School[];
}
```

Without interceptor, everything is working fine (except that password is still visible). Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've told GraphQL you will be returning a `User` object which has the non-nullable field `password` on it. You've also told `class-transformer` that when `plainToClass` is ran, the `password` field **must** be removed. So now GraphQL is upset because you've broken the object contract you've said should be there (the returned object **must** have a `password` field) because you've told another library to remove that field.

You have a few options here:

1. use `@Field({ nullable: true })` to tell GraphQL this field doesn't have to be returned. This does still mean that someone can query for that field and it will always be `undefined` though
2. Remove the `password` `@Field()` annotation because it should not be returned on a `user` query and only keep it on the `@InputType()` object.

### Edit

Thanks for an answer from the comments of this answer, you're returning an object from the database instead of an instance of the `User` class. If what your database returns have class-transformer decorators you'll want to check what could be happening there (such as possibly excluding fields). Also, note that returning mongoose objects does have [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60525544/how-to-serialize-a-nest-js-response-with-class-transformer-while-getting-data-wi) with class-transformer directly, and you may need to transform the database return to a plain JSON and then to a class for `class-transformer` to properly work

Comment: Thanks, @jay-mcdoniel for a quick answer. I check both suggestions. The first suggestion does not change anything still gets the same result (all fields are null). And the second one will be ok for now. But I'm still curious why ClassSerializerInterceptor is not working as I expected with all graphql methods in Resolver. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I misread part of the question, sorry about that. What does `this.userService.editById` return? Is it an instance of `User` or is it an entity object from your database (assuming TypeORM here as most people use that). You'll probably also need to show the `Teacher` definition here as we don't have the full picture.

Comment: I added the teacher object in the question. Userservice is returning the object from database with use of mongosee `this.instanceModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, item, { new:  true }).exec();`

Comment: Thanks @jay-mcdoniel . You are right to properly work with `class-tranformer` on the side of UserResolver every object should be transformed with `plainToClass`. So working example in mutation should look like `const user = await this.usersService.editById(id, item);
    const userClass = plainToClass(User, user.toJSON());
    return userClass;`

Answer (score 0):

you may use as this example https://gist.github.com/EndyKaufman/aa8a7ebb750540217a08fac72292a9c2

```
import { CallHandler, ClassSerializerInterceptor, ExecutionContext, Injectable, Logger, Module, PlainLiteralObject, SetMetadata, Type } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR, Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ClassTransformOptions, plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export const GQL_RETURN_TYPE = 'GQL_RETURN_TYPE';

export const GqlReturn = (type: Type<any>) => SetMetadata('GQL_RETURN_TYPE', type);

@Resolver()
export class PaymentBalanceResolver {
    @GqlReturn(BalanceDto)
    @Query(() => BalanceDto, {
        nullable: false,
    })
    getUserBalance(@CurrentUser() currentUser: CurrentUserType): Observable<BalanceDto> {
        return this.paymentBalanceService.getUserBalance(currentUser.id);
    }
}

@Module({
    providers: [
        {
            provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
            useFactory: (reflector: any): ClassSerializerInterceptor => new ClassSerializerInterceptor(reflector),
            inject: [Reflector],
        },
        PaymentBalanceResolver,
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}

@Injectable()
export class CoreClassSerializerInterceptor extends ClassSerializerInterceptor {
    private readonly logger = new Logger(CoreClassSerializerInterceptor.name);

    constructor(protected readonly reflector: any, defaultOptions?: ClassTransformOptions) {
        super(reflector, defaultOptions);
        this.logger.log('create');
    }

    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
        if ((context.getType() as string) === 'graphql') {
            const op = context.getArgByIndex(3).operation.operation;
            if (op === 'subscription') {
                return next.handle();
            }
            const contextOptions = this.getContextOptions(context);
            const options = {
                ...this.defaultOptions,
                ...contextOptions,
            };
            return next
                .handle()
                .pipe(
                    map((res: PlainLiteralObject | Array<PlainLiteralObject>) =>
                        this.serialize(res, { ...options, returnClass: Reflect.getMetadata(GQL_RETURN_TYPE, context.getHandler()) })
                    )
                );
        }
        return next.handle();
    }

    serialize(
        response: PlainLiteralObject | Array<PlainLiteralObject>,
        options: ClassTransformOptions & { returnClass: any }
    ): PlainLiteralObject | Array<PlainLiteralObject> {
        try {
            const result = super.serialize(options.returnClass ? plainToClass(options.returnClass, response) : response, options);
            return result;
        } catch (err) {
            this.logger.debug(response);
            this.logger.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your answer. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations.