# Typescript Mongoose ignore certain field in query result the type safe way

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I am using Nestjs and Mongoose. I need to fetch a user profile but ignore the password from Mongodb.

My user schema looks like this

```
@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Prop({required: true})
  password: string;
}
```

When the user logs in, I need to fetch the user with the password so that I can authenticate the user. Here is the findOne method in UsersService. It uses `User` the schema as the type

```
async findOne(filter: FilterQuery<User>): Promise<User> {
    return this.userModel.findOne(filter).exec();
}
```

However, in my authentication method, after the user is authenticated, I need to return the user without the password.

```
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<User | null> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne({ email });
    if (user && await compare(password, user.password)) {
      const {password: ignore, ...result} = user.toObject();
      return result;
    }

    return null;
  }
```

This works, but `user.toObject()` returns type `any` which will ignore the type check. I  still would like `validateUser` method to make sure I return a promise of `User` or `null`

Is there a type safe way to do so? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful... thanks

Comment: Yes. Very helpful. Accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to transform your plain JavaScript object returned by `toObject` into a typed object, you might want to use `class-transformer` library (the library is recommended by [`Nest.js`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator) for validation purposes).

**Step 1.**

First install `class-validator`:

```
$ npm i --save class-transformer
```

**Step 2.**

Once installed, assuming `User` class has the following properties:

```js
 class User {
     public id: any;
     public email: string;
     public password: number;
 }
```

Create antoher class named `UserWithoutPassward` and import `Exclude`

```
import { Exclude } from "class-transformer";

class UserWithoutPassword extends User {
    @Exclude()
    public password: number
}
```

We use `Exclude` annotation to let `class-transformer` know we would like to exclude `password`.

**Step 3.**

import the `plainToClass` function:

```
import { plainToClass } from "class-transformer";
```

And back to your code:

```
async validateUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<UserWithoutPassword | null> {
    const user = await this.usersService.findOne({ email });

    if (user && await compare(password, user.password))
    {
        return plainToClass(UserWithoutPassword, user.toObject());
    }

    return null;
}
```

`plainToClass` method transforms a plain javascript object to instance of specific class, accepting the following parameters:

1. The class to instantiate
2. plain object

[Further reference about the library](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer)

Hope it helps.