# How to exclude a parameter returned from controller

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm, e2e-testing

I want to exclude lastsync parameter. I am testing my code from the ts file

```
  @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
  public async cameraRegistered(
    @Body(SubscriptionPipe) body: DeviceRegisteredTopic,
  ) {
    return this.schedule.getByProjectId(body.projectId).then(async (s) => {
      console.log(s);
      const ds = await this.schedule.desynchronize(s);
      const tbs = await ds.timeblocks;
      return this.pubsub
        .publishUpdateArming({
          arming: tbs.filter((t) => t.type === BlockType.ARMING),
          timelapse: tbs.filter((t) => t.type === BlockType.TIMELAPSE),
          scheduleId: ds.id,
          projectId: ds.projectId,
          lastSync: ds.lastSync,
          createdBy: ds.author,
        }as UpdateArmingEvent)
       //.then();
    });
  }
```

I have written a test case for end 2 end testing just for spying the publishUpdateArming

```
it('should handle device registered events for projects without a schedule', async () => {
      const publishUpdateArmingSpy = jest.spyOn(publishService, 'publishUpdateArming');
      const date = new Date(
        new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString('en-US', {
          timeZone: 'Europe/Berlin',
        }),
      );

      let s = new Schedule();
      s.archived = false;
      s.author = 'test-runner';
      s.createdAt = new Date();
      //s.lastSync = new Date();
      s.projectId = projectId;
      s.synchronized = true;

      s = await getConnection().manager.save(s);

      let tb = new Timeblock();
      (tb.dayOfWeek = date.getDay() === 0 ? 7 : date.getDay()),
        (tb.startTime = Math.max(
          date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes() - 5,
          0,
        )),
        (tb.endTime = Math.min(
          date.getHours() * 60 + date.getMinutes() + 5,
          1440,
        )),
        (tb.type = BlockType.TIMELAPSE);
      tb.scheduleId = s.id;

      const timeb = [await getConnection().manager.save(tb)];

      const armingEvent= {
        arming: timeb.filter((t) => t.type === BlockType.ARMING),
        timelapse: timeb.filter((t) => t.type === BlockType.TIMELAPSE),
        scheduleId: s.id,
        projectId: s.projectId,
        //lastSync: s.lastSync,
        createdBy: s.author,
      }

      const deviceRegisteredTopic: DeviceRegisteredTopic= {
        projectId: projectId,
        deviceId: 'deviceId',
      }

      const res = await req.post(url).send(toSubscription(deviceRegisteredTopic));
     // res.body.toString()
      console.log("after await statement"+res.body);
      console.log(res.body.projectId);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res.body.projectId));
      console.log(" Log 1 "+publishUpdateArmingSpy)
      console.log("Log 2 "+ JSON.stringify(armingEvent))
      expect(publishUpdateArmingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(classToPlain(armingEvent));
       
    });    
  });
```

I have also defined my lastsync parameter as

```
  @IsString()
  @Exclude({toPlainOnly : true})
  lastSync: string | Date;
```

But when I am running my code I am getting the below error

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    - Expected
    + Received

    @@ -1,12 +1,13 @@
      Object {
        "arming": Array [],
        "createdBy": "test-runner",
    +   "lastSync": 2021-10-27T09:57:23.990Z,
        "projectId": "e02998f0-c9d2-414f-9ab0-e45063e672a2",
        "scheduleId": "5087fea3-b46a-4e9a-9104-e2d485897e42",
        "timelapse": Array [
    -     Object {
    +     Timeblock {
            "dayOfWeek": 3,
            "endTime": 722,
            "id": "6382dd0d-ed25-41ef-8682-573e953d3734",
            "scheduleId": "5087fea3-b46a-4e9a-9104-e2d485897e42",
            "startTime": 712,,

    Number of calls: 1

      254 |       console.log(" Log 1 "+publishUpdateArmingSpy)
      255 |       console.log("Log 2 "+ JSON.stringify(armingEvent))
    > 256 |       expect(publishUpdateArmingSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(classToPlain(armingEvent));
          |                                      ^
      257 |
      258 |     });
      259 |   });
```

I am not sure where I am doing mistakes. I need help. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360101/how-to-exclude-entity-field-from-returned-by-controller-json-nestjs-typeorm/54277187#54277187

Comment: I have seen this. My lastsync parameter from the test file is removed but it is still receiving the parameter from the ts file. So, can you please let me know to handle that?