# Hide sensible data from the user in the response NestJS/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nestjs

I started to play with `nest` in the last week and even if I found it super useful there is a few thing that I can't replicate from a classic `Express/Mongoose` app.
One of this things is giving sensitive data as a password in a return.

For example in an `Express/Mongoose` app, I will do this to clean what the User can see:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Name is required"],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
    unique: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Password is required"],
  },
  img: {
    type: String,
  },
  rol: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    emun: ["ADMIN_ROL", "USER_ROL"],
  },
  state: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
  },
  google: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
});

UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
  const { __v, _id, password, ...user } = this.toObject();
  user.uid = _id;
  return user;
};

module.exports = model("Users", UserSchema);
```

Like you see, I implement the methods of the class to clean the `user` object and return a secure and clean response.

Meanwhile the similar way of creating an user schema witn `NestJS/Mongoose` is this:

```js
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

export type UserDocument = User & Document;

@Schema()
export class User {
  @Prop({
    required: [true, 'Name is required'],
  })
  name: string;
  @Prop({
    required: [true, 'Password is required'],
  })
  password: string;
  @Prop()
  img: string;
  @Prop({
    required: true,
    enum: ['ADMIN_ROL', 'USER_ROL'],
  })
  rol: string;
  @Prop({
    default: true,
  })
  state: boolean;
  @Prop({
    default: false,
  })
  google: boolean;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

Very basic just fallowing the `NestJS` documentation.

Which is the best way to achieve the same result with Nest?

Also I will like the ask you any blog/youtuber that work with nest, it will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to completely separate the REST API model from the database model by having a DTO class which contains the fields you want to return over the REST API and a separate Entity class which defines the fields to be used in the Mongoose schema and write a mapper function that sets the fields in the response DTO based on a given entity object.

The downside of this:
You will be maintaining more lines of code and need to change your mapper each time you introduce new fields.

The benefits of this:

- You cannot accidentally return fields containing sensitive data which is not already defined by the DTO.
- You have a single place for the conversion that can be reused across all API endpoints returning that object (potentially as nested child property in some other aggregated resource).
  Consider a case where another application or MongoDB script changes the documents in your database. You don't want renamed fields to appear in the response. This is why the `Omit` type mentioned by @Enver Arslan should be avoided because it would not reflect field renames under all circumstances.
- Your API will not suddenly have different field names just because you renamed a field in the database. This will help you keeping your API more stable.

Other this you should keep in mind:
Always hash+salt your users's passwords with a strong hashing algorithm like bcrypt/scrypt. Follow OWASPs latest advisories on that topic.

Always encrypt sensitive data in transit and at rest (HTTPS, symmetric encryption, etc.)

Always filter your output data using a whitelisting oriented approach wherever possible.
You should never assume the data in your database is sanitized because in more complex use cases, other applications might be writing to the same database, too. A street name usually doesn't start with "DROP TABLE", right? ;)
That filtering might be placed in the mapper function as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change your schema as in this example:

```
...
password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Password is required"],
    select: false
  },
...
```

add the select prop and set  false, if you want to hide fields

Comment: If the field would be renamed in the documents inside mongodb, depending on the entity mapper framework, it might occur that the field will be exposed over the API again. This is why I suggest a separate DTO with mapper function in my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75436936/4397899

Answer (score -1):

Nest.js provides [Mapped Types](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/mapped-types) from [OpenAPI](https://swagger.io/specification/) specification.

You can create [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)s with using `PartialType`, `OmitType`, `PickType` functions.

Comment: Omit is dangerous because it would not reflect field renames under all circumstances. See my alternative answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75436936/4397899