# How to exclude property from selecting in SQL Query? NestJS, typeorm

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm, nest

I'd like to exclude certain properties in the output for users. For example, I want to protect password hash from users and never get it as the answer.

This solution didn't work

```
@Exclude()
@Column()
passwordHash: string;
```

Comment: This post looks like it should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360101/how-to-exclude-entity-field-from-returned-by-controller-json-nestjs-typeorm

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Column({ select: false })
passwordHash: string
```