# Exclude() is not working on nestjs post method response but working on get response

Tags: serialization, nestjs, typeorm, class-validator, class-transformer

***user.entity.ts***

```
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;
...
@Column()
@IsString()
@Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
password: string;
```

***user.controller.ts***

```
@Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return this.usersService.create(createUserDto);
  }
```

***user.service.ts***

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) { }

  async create(createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    ...
    return await this.usersRepository.save(createUserDto);
  }
...
}
```

***main.ts***

```
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true, transform: true }));
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));
```

When I am returning post response from the service I am getting the response with password that I already excluded from entity and also globally provided with "ClassSerializerInterceptor". But in my get request of getAllUser I don't get "password" field.

**I am looking for a solution that when I create a user the "password" field will not be in the response but want it internally.**

Comment: Please checkout this Answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360101/how-to-exclude-entity-field-from-returned-by-controller-json-nestjs-typeorm

Comment: I have gone through all of them. Doesn't work in my case.